# How to generate Datarows based on a delimiter in a Datacolumn from a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, .net-datatable

In my office, we use a software called Blue Prism, a Robotic Process Automation System. The idea is to allocate tasks for the robots to perform thereby simulating users. The system enables you to use a code stage ( with an option of C# with dotnet framework 2.0) and to import some objects in C#, you require a DataTable.  My problem is

> Currently, The datatable has one row with ID, FirstName, Initial and LastName as a columns but the chances are thousands of rows will be added subsequently.
>
> The row contains values such as

```
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Mary;Josh;Sam", "K;;", "Edward;Rashidi;Martha" });
```

but what i want is

```
FirstName    Initial     LastName
Mary           K          Edward
Josh                      Rashidi
Sam                       Grunua
```

P.S I have never had to use so many nested loops until now because Linq existed and it's currently not available in .net 2.0

Based on my research of DataTable, when you are aiming at retrieving data faster you use DataTableReader. Hence I used it here. I defined four methods

1. `PrintColumns(DataTableReader reader)` - to print out all the cells of
   the datatable
2. `TransformDataTble(Datatable datatable)` - which generates the new
   datatable i am aiming for
3. `GetCustomers()` - returns an input datatable containing required data
4. `TestCreateDataReader(Datatable dt)` - to check if the datatable has
   rows before attempting to print. Hence this calls printColumns()

---

```
 public static DataTable TransformDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            DataRow row;
            int counter = 0;
            DataTable newTable = new DataTable("FormattedTable");
            // Gives the newtable the same column Names as the oldtabble
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                newTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }
            using (System.Data.DataTableReader reader = dataTable.CreateDataReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(reader[i]).Contains(";")
                            {
                                String[] splitString = Convert.ToString(reader[i]).Split(Convert.ToChar(";"));
                                foreach (string item2 in splitString)
                                {
                                    if (newTable.Rows.Count != splitString.Length)
                                    {
                                        row = newTable.NewRow();
                                        row[reader.GetName(i)] = item2;
                                        newTable.Rows.Add(row);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        for (int j = counter; j < newTable.Rows.Count;)
                                        {
                                            newTable.Rows[j][reader.GetName(i)] = item2;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return newTable;
            }
        }
```

---

```
private static void PrintColumns(DataTableReader reader)
    {
        // Loop through all the rows in the DataTableReader
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(reader[i] + " ");
                var b = reader[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
```

---

```
   private static void TestCreateDataReader(DataTable dt)
        {
            // Given a DataTable, retrieve a DataTableReader
            // allowing access to all the tables' data:
            using (DataTableReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader())
            {
                do
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Empty DataTableReader");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PrintColumns(reader);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("========================");
                } while (reader.NextResult());
            }
        }
```

---

```
 private static DataTable GetCustomers()
        {
            // Create sample Customers table, in order
            // to demonstrate the behavior of the DataTableReader.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Create two columns, ID and Name.
            DataColumn idColumn = table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Initial", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
            //table.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(string));
            //table.Columns.Add("Member", typeof(string));
            //table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(string));

            // Set the ID column as the primary key column.
            table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { idColumn };

            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Mary;Josh;Sam", "k;;", "Edward;rashidi;Grunua" });

            return table;
        }
                    } while (reader.NextResult());
                }
            }
```

So far this code works, but i know his can be improved . Any suggestions would be helpful

P.S kindly comment on other forms of implemetations asides Linq as Linq is non existent in the .net 2.0 framework

Comment: I'm not sure if this is realy working. There is `splitString.Count()` in the first method which is definitely linq and doesn't compile for .net 2.0. Also the `reader[i]).Contains((char)59)` is illegal in .net 2.0. Are you not telling us something? You seem to be using linq anyway. Are you sure you're working with .net 2.0 and not something higher like 3.5?

Comment: @t3chb0t I noticed my mistake after migrating my code . I also made amends to that thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move code to methods. By the time you hit `for (int j = counter; j < newTable.Rows.Count;)` you're nearly ten levels deep. Not only are you losing valuable screen estate, it also doesn't help the clarity of your code.

You could also use `continue;` to reduce indentation:

```
if (!reader.HasRows)
{
   continue;
}
```

And:

```
if (!Convert.ToString(reader[i]).Contains(";")
{
   continue;
}
```

---

I don't see the point of defining `DataRow row;` at the top, considering `row` is only used inside `if (newTable.Rows.Count != splitString.Length)`.

---

Why don't you simply [`Clone()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) the `DataTable` instead of doing `foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)`?

---

`Convert.ToString(reader[i])` is used twice, so perhaps it would be beneficial to store its results. Same for `reader.GetName(i)`, and in that case it is even more important considering it is used inside a loop.

---

The name of `item2` doesn't tell me anything about what it contains.

---

Avoid "negative" logic like `if (newTable.Rows.Count != splitString.Length)` ... `else`; instead do it the other way around: `if (newTable.Rows.Count == splitString.Length)`.

---

`";"` should be defined as a `private const char`, and that variable should be used in [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) instead of `Contains(";")`; that way you can also avoid `Convert.ToChar(";")`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, bbut the second datatable is a modified version as it doesn't contain the same elements as the original

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo That method "clones the **structure** of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas and constraints."

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense now